# How to detect runtime error in c program?

Tags: c, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception, segmentation-fault

I am having runtime error in the following part of my code.

```
int sacrificeCounter(int board[][5], int row, int col, int count)
{
    if ((row >= 0) && (row < 5) && (col >= 0) && (col < 5))
    {
        if (row > 0)
            if (containsElement(&topSacrifice[0], board[row][col], 3))
                if (containsElement(&notToChoose[0], board[row - 1][col], 6))
                {
                    count = sacrificeCounter(board, row - 1, col, count + 1);
                }
        if (row < 4)
            if (containsElement(&bottomSacrifice[0], board[row][col], 3))
                if (containsElement(&notToChoose[0], board[row + 1][col], 6))
                {
                    count = sacrificeCounter(board, row + 1, col, count + 1);
                }
        if (col > 0)
            if (containsElement(&leftSacrifice[0], board[row][col], 3))
                if (containsElement(&notToChoose[0], board[row][col - 1], 6))
                {
                    count = sacrificeCounter(board, row, col - 1, count + 1);
                }
        if (col < 4)
            if (containsElement(&rightSacrifice[0], board[row][col], 3))
                if (containsElement(&notToChoose[0], board[row][col + 1], 6))
                {
                    count = sacrificeCounter(board, row, col + 1, count + 1);
                }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Dev cpp compilation window freezes and closes. Sometimes, it says **SIGSEGV error** before closing the compilation window. I searched about SIGSEGV and found that it is mostly caused when array bounds exceeds. But I don't see where it exceeds. I added an extra if condition(the first one among the consecutive three) to make sure the array index stays in its bounds. But no help.

When I comment `count=sacrifice...` (all the four lines), there is no error. But of course, I didn't get the desired output. Here `board` is a 5x5 matrix. Both `row` and `col` values lies between 0-4 and `count` value is 1 initially when the function is called.

> Note:- I am calling this function only one time in my entire code. But, its a recursive function which calls itself multiple times.

Comment: Why do you think the recursion would end?

Comment: Did you run it through a debugger?

Comment: Runtime errors are detected by: (1) error messages from the system (*e.g.*, exceptions), (2) internal checks in your program that check values for validity and alert the user if they are wrong (e.g., usage of *assert*), or (3) you get what you know are incorrect results (as in this case) and you use a debugger and/or insert additional checks in your code to detect where it went wrong.

Comment: Why not printf out row,col,count at the top?

Comment: Regarding your array, how are you calling this function, or more importantly, where/how did you allocate the space for the array argument, `board[][5]`? How is the input array declared and defined? Are you sure you have at least 5 rows available in the input array?

Comment: ..or use your debugger, as suggested by @Haris, and put a breakpoint at the top so you can inspect the parameters etc.

Comment: What logically defines the end of your recursion? I see that it's when either the column or row index goes out of bounds, but when and how are assured that it will happen?

Comment: @martin James, I don't know about debugging. Could you suggest a place where I can read about dev cpp debugging?

Comment: @luker, the matrix is 5x5. That's 100% sure. And the recursion comes to an end when there is no adjacent box which has two edges filled. ( this is a piece from dots and box game).

Comment: I understand that's the desired behavior, but obviously something's not right. What about how your input array is declared and defined as I asked previously?

Comment: @HariRam so, what if there is an adjacent box with 2 edged filled?

Comment: Summary `do { when it decends into the *EAST* cell, it could from there descend into the *WEST* cell again} while (1)`

Comment: @grek40, if adjacent box is two edge filled, count is incremented and function is called again by making the adjacent box as current box

Comment: why there is no `else if` in your code?. suppose col=row=3, all ifs that comes will be satisfied and executed, thus `count ` will be incremented multiple times.

Comment: @wildplasser, that's the spark in my dark. I think that should be my problem. Will confirm it by upgrading the algorithm